# Yes / No Function Always Returning False :(

Tags: python, boolean

I'm completely new to programming and am trying to write a function that takes a yes or no question. However, when I run the below it always seems to complete with my variable as False. There has to be something simple here that I'm missing. I'd love to hear any thoughts / feedback / improvements to it. Thank you!

```
def yes_or_no(question):
    answer = input(question).lower().strip()
    print("")
    while not(answer == "y" or answer == "yes" or \
    answer == "n" or answer == "no"):
        print("\nSorry, only Y or N please.")
        answer = input(question).lower().strip()
        print("")
        print(answer)
    if answer == 'y' or answer == 'yes':
        answer = True
    else:
        answer = False
```

Comment: Did you mean to return something from this function?

Comment: Theres no reason I see that answer should be always `False`. You are missing a `return answer` at the end, but in that case you would get `None` not `False`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return the `answer`, so that function returns `None` by default. Add `return answer` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was missing something simple!

Comment: If the answer was correct, think about marking it as such. This will let others know that this answer is solved ;)